# How to use a vertex ai model after saving it on my local machine to predict new data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

How can I use a saved model from vertex ai to predict the classes of new data on my computer

I used vertex ai tabular model to train a model, then I dowloaded the resulting model on my local machine. I wish to use to the saved model on my computer to predict new data. I have been researching and reading alot about how to do this but couldn't find anything that tackles this issue in specific.

Answer (score 0):

to use the exported Vertex AI Tabular models, you need to use a pre-baked container image that is able to load the model and run inferences.

You may find the directions about how to do it on the [Export AutoML tabular models documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-model-tabular#pull-and-run-server).